# Recognize math expression on bitmap images

Tags: algorithm, math, latex, ocr, image-recognition

**What i need**

User uploads image with handwritten/printed math expression and gets its mathml/latex/etc as output.

**What i tried**

Here around the web is many good tools such as Seshat (http://cat.prhlt.upv.es/mer/) that already does what i need but only using some vector path/strokes as input. So instead of doing large classification research i would rather try to convert simple handwritten/printed math bitmaps to strokes using something like http://potrace.sourceforge.net/. The main problem with that concept is strokes that would be generated that way wouldn't be recognized by seshat or other tool in most cases cause lot of garbage paths. So may anyone help me with improving my solution or find any good classification tool for such purpose?